# netbeans not using auto-props eol-style for svn

Tags: svn, netbeans

We are using SVN with NetBeans (SVNKit).
Unfortunately, my colleague changed some settings on his client (TortoiseSVN) on Windows and committed his version. After updating, i am no longer able to commit any changes, as NetBeans complains:

```
Please set the eol-style manually (to native) or check how to set it globally in your client for new files.
```

In my SVN configs, i have the according settings:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.java = svn:eol-style=native
*.xhtml = svn:eol-style=native
<more entries>
```

However, as I read, these properties will be only applied to new files, so what would be the cause of this error in NetBeans? I didn't create any new files, just updated some. Could it be that TortoiseSVN also applies these properties to updated files?

I'm sorry for the somewhat unclear question, but my colleague is on vacation for several weeks... :(

Answer (score 0):

OK after some debugging following results arose:
My colleague installed an extra script on the server that checked if all files that are contained in an incoming commit have the "eol-style" property set. I am the only one using Linux + NetBeans + SVNKit, the others didn't notice the error, which leads to the suspicion that TortoiseSVN also applies the auto-props for updated files, whereas SVNKit only applies them to new files.